# Partition of unity subordinate to a cover and its refinement

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds

I am reading the book "Manifolds and Differential Geometry" by Jeffrey M Lee, and in the initial chapter, I came across the concept of partition of unity. As a reference to the question I am about to ask, here is its definition:

**Definition (Partition of Unity):** A partition of unity on a smooth manifold $M$ is a collection of smooth functions $\left\lbrace \phi_{\alpha} \right\rbrace_{\alpha \in \Delta}$ on $M$ such that

(1) For each $\alpha \in \Delta$, $0 \leq \phi_{\alpha} \leq 1$.

(2) The collection of supports $\left\lbrace \text{supp} \left( \phi_{\alpha} \right) \right\rbrace_{\alpha \in \Delta}$ is locally finite, i.e., for each point $p \in M$, there is an open set $W_p \subseteq M$ with $p \in W_p$ such that $W_p \cap \text{supp} \left( \phi_{\alpha} \right) = \emptyset$ for all but finitely many $\alpha \in \Delta$.

(3) For each $p \in M$, we have $\sum\limits_{\alpha \in \Delta} \phi_{\alpha} \left( p \right) = 1$.

A partition of unity $\left\lbrace \phi_{\alpha} \right\rbrace_{\alpha \in \Delta}$ will be called subordinate to an open cover $\left\lbrace U_{\alpha} \right\rbrace_{\alpha \in \Delta}$ if for each $\alpha \in \Delta$, we have $\text{supp} \left( \phi_{\alpha} \right) \subseteq U_{\alpha}$.

In a remark that follows this definition, the author tells us that if we have an open cover $\left\lbrace U_{\alpha} \right\rbrace_{\alpha \in \Delta}$, and its refinement $\left\lbrace W_{\lambda} \right\rbrace_{\lambda \in \Lambda}$ and there is a partition of unity $\left\lbrace \psi_{\lambda} \right\rbrace_{\lambda \in \Lambda}$ subordinate to $\left\lbrace W_{\lambda} \right\rbrace_{\lambda \in \Lambda}$, then we can construct a partition of unity $\left\lbrace \phi_{\alpha} \right\rbrace_{\alpha \in \Delta}$, as

$$\phi_{\alpha} = \sum\limits_{\lambda \in f^{-1} \left( \alpha \right)} \psi_{\lambda}.$$

Here, $f: \Lambda \rightarrow \Delta$ is a map such that $W_{\lambda} \subseteq U_{f \left( \lambda \right)}$ (making $\left\lbrace W_{\lambda} \right\rbrace_{\lambda \in \Lambda}$ a refinement of $\left\lbrace U_{\alpha} \right\rbrace_{\alpha \in \Delta}$).

I was trying to verify that the remark made by the author is indeed true. However, I am stuck in verifying the last step. I want to see that

$$\sum\limits_{\alpha \in \Delta} \phi_{\alpha} = \sum\limits_{\alpha \in \Delta} \sum\limits_{\lambda \in f^{-1} \left( \alpha \right)} \psi_{\lambda} = 1.$$

So, my guess is that I should be able to convert the double sum over a single sum on $\lambda$. However, I do not know how to do it. Is it got something to do with the collection of supports being locally finite? Or that the support will be contained in the respective open set (since the partition is subordinate to a cover)?

Comment: Jeffrey M. Lee ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The collection of subsets $\{f^{-1}(\alpha)\mid \alpha\in\Delta\}$ are disjoint and cover $\Lambda$ (removing the empty sets in this collection gives a partition of $\Lambda$). Hence summing over all $\lambda\in f^{-1}(\alpha)$, then summing over all $\alpha\in\Delta$, is the same as summing over all $\lambda\in\Lambda$.